# Python: How to set a class variable based on a parameter to __init__()?

Tags: python, class

I have a class C. 
I would like to instantiate this class with one argument. Let's call that argument d. 
So I would like to do myC = C(d=5). 
C should also have another variable called e. e's value should be set to d on instantiation of the class.

So I wrote this:

```
>>> class C:
...     def __init__(self,d):
...         self.d = d
...     e = d
...
```

But that gives me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in C
NameError: name 'd' is not defined
```

Ok fine, So I will try something slightly different:

```
>>> class C:
...     def __init__(self,d):
...         self.d = d
...     e = self.d
...
```

But that gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in C
NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

So how should I do what I'm trying to do?? This should be very simple.

Answer (score 8):

You need to make `e` part of the `__init__` method as well. `d` is not defined until that function is called:

```
class C:
    def __init__(self,d):
        self.d = d
        self.e = d
```

You can put these on the same line if you want to:

```
class C:
    def __init__(self,d):
        self.d = self.e = d
```

If you need `e` to be a class attribute instead of an instance attribute, refer directly to the class:

```
class C:
    def __init__(self,d):
        self.d = d
        C.e = d
```

or use `type(self)`:

```
class C:
    def __init__(self,d):
        self.d = d
        type(self).e = d
```

The latter means that if you subclass `C`, the class attribute will be set on the appropriate subclass instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
class C:
    def __init__(self,d):
        self.d = self.e = d
```